# Aligning top of one object with bottom of a channel

Tags: modeling

Im very new to blender.

I want to align objects. I learned to make a small carve out to tuck something into inside a box, but I want a support to help hold it up

Does blender have an easy way to align the top of one object with the bottom of my carve out? See the picture[image]

So I want the top of my support block aligned with the bottom of that channel

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving this:

### Method 1 (easiest)

Go into *Edit Mode* for both objects, set your orbit mode (the period key I believe) to *Active Element*, then select the top of the object first, and then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the face of the channel that you would like the object to align with. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, <kbd>Z</kbd> to select the vertical axis, and type `0`.

### Method 2

Select the face of the channel you want it to align to, open up the XYZ position tab, make sure the mode is set to global, and copy the Z coordinate.  Then, select the top face of the object, and paste the Z coordinate into its XYZ position tab.

Comment: Thanks. Im trying method one, but once I select my cubes face, Im unable to select my frames face.  If I select my frames face first, Im unable to select my cubes face. Im not sure what might cause this.

Comment: Are both faces part of the same object?  If not, make sure you shift+select both objects before entering edit mode, and then you should be able to shift+select both faces.